# How do you implement a list vs. an arraylist

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm a java beginner and I know that you should use list over arraylist but i'm not exactly sure how to change from arraylist to list. 
Before I had

```
ArrayList<Homework3> hw = new ArrayList<Homework3>();
```

Which worked and then I tried:

```
List<Homework3> hw = new ArrayList<Homework3>();
```

Then I tried to implement the List interface with this:

```
public interface List<Homework3> // inheritance not shown 
{ 
 boolean add( Homework3 x ); 
 void add( int index, Homework3 x ); 
 Homework3 get( int index ); 
 Homework3 remove( int index ); 
 Homework3 set( int index, Homework3 x ); 
 int size(); 
}
```

But now it's saying incompatible types. I looked at other questions and discussions and they had the code just like this:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

And i'm following the same basic principle, can someone help explain why it isn't working and how I can fix this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "implement List"? And don't omit type information (inheritance) when that's what you're asking about. It sounds like you are unclear on what the concept of a Java interface is.

Comment: `java.util.ArrayList` is an implementation of the `java.util.List` `interface` and a `reference` to a parent type can refer to a child object. therefore, `java.util.List<SomeObject> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>()` is a valid statement. If you implement your own `List` then `java.util.ArrayList` will not be a sub-type of your custom `List` thus the statement `List<SomeObject> myList = new java.util.ArrayList<>()` will not be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `java.util.ArrayList` implements `java.util.List` interface. Hence your code after defining your own `List<Homework3>` interface would have incompatible types.

```
    List<Object> list     =    new ArrayList<Object>();
//  ^^                               ^^
// your.package.List            java.util.ArrayList
```

---

Similar code in your question

```
    List<Homework3> hw  =   new ArrayList<Homework3>();
//  ^^                               ^^
// java.util.List            java.util.ArrayList
```

would have worked earlier since then you didn't introduce the `List` interface as mentioned in the question and you were referring to `java.util.List` itself.

Comment: I removed the java.util.ArrayList and now it says cannot find symbol over the arraylist

Comment: @user9986762 If you're planning to define your own `List` interface and `ArrayList` class, then you would have to create one. Also note, you should rename such instances to refrain from class name conflicts and incorrect imports, something like `CustomList` and `CustomArrayList`.

Comment: List<Homework3> hw = new ArrayList<Homework3>(); and I removed the list class. I also removed the import statement at the top of the code

Comment: Now it cannot find the "List" and the "ArrayList" symbol so what can I do to get it working just like an arraylist again while keeping the 
"List"

Comment: *I removed the list class. I also removed the import statement at the top of the code* ... you should now use the imports for JDK classes .. `import java.uti.List; import java.util.ArrayList;`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do *any* of this.  Java takes care of this type resolution for you through [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Because [`List<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) is defined in a generic way, so too must its implementors be, and thus [`ArrayList<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html) uses the same generic type declared by the interface.

To be explicit:
When you declare `List<Homework3> hw = new ArrayList<Homework3>();`, **everywhere** that `E` is used in the Javadoc is replaced by `Homework3`.  You don't have to implement *any* of this because the language already has for you.

Comment: List<Homework3> hw = new ArrayList<Homework3>(); and I removed the list class